# User's Domain Roles not recognized by Views

Tags: views, users, domain-access

We have upgraded our Drupal platform from 7.32 to 7.41, and upgraded [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) from 3.9 to 3.12.

After the upgrade our Views that evaluate user's domain roles are not returning any role for the logged in user (not even "authenticated user"), but if I add a PHP field and print_r($user), then all the roles are displayed.

If I edit the user and assign a role, then the View evaluates correctly, but we need the roles applied per domain and not per user.

Any suggestions?